# How to use IOS Switch in Xamarin Forms Both IOS and Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[Ios Switchs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvgJD.png)

I want to add this type of Switches for my Xamarin Froms project.It should work for both IOS and Android.Please Help me to do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the time to read the following:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: People expect an Android app to have native Android switches, not iOS looking ones. It would be jarring to see.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way.
It's just not how Xamarin works. It invokes native implementation on both platforms.

But you can make yourself a control that looks like iOS switch.
I suggest you to try NControl for that.

The second option is just to style default Android control.

Comment: thank you. Can you provide something about  NControl?

Comment: Here's the library with some examples: https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl